# Inserting images using Adobe Acrobat Professional

Tags: image, adobe, acrobat

Im trying to work with this tool, Acrobat, and I find it not very user friendly tbh...

What I'm trying to do right now is to insert some images into and between the text, and I only can do it through the "Stamps" tools..

Is there another way to do this?, cuz it kinda sucks.

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

attempt to insert a button, and then Define the background button with the corresponding image